# Выборка данных за последние 30 секунд

Tags: php, выборка, mysql

Выборка данных за последние 30 секунд:

```
$l = time() - (0.3 * 60);
$q = $db->query("SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `ttime` > '$l'");
$d = $db->fetch($d);
```

Есть ли другой способ выбрать данные за последние 30 секунд с помощью операторов SQL?

Comment: time() - (0.3 * 60); - это что вообще такое?

0,3*60=30 секунд?

Comment: @Shrek, да

Comment: @ModaL, ну, вообще-то, не совсем.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хранить TIMESTAMP в базе лучше средствами SQL без вмешательства PHP и тогда можно будет без лишних телодвижений спрашивать по времени

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mytimestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 SECOND
```

!писал по памяти, могут быть ошибки!

Comment: @qpaycm, у меня не работает потому, что я храню метку о времени(timestamp) как int(10)? Потому что ошибок никаких не выдаёт и информации тоже.

Comment: Не выдаёт потому, что time() - это UNIX_TIMESTAMP. Попробуйте так
>> SELECT * FROM table WHERE unixtimestamp >=(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 30)